# How to open my app's external/shared storage directory

Tags: android, file, directory, file-browser

I have a notification displaying progress of downloading a file. Upon completion, tapping on it should open the directory in which the file was saved (my app's external storage directory). The intent is set up in the following way and is later passed to a PendingIntent.

```
val dir = getExternalFilesDir("storage")
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
intent.data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, authority, dir)
intent.type = DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR
```

What actually happens - the file explorer opens, but shows "Recent" directory(?) instead.

What else I tried:

- passing absolute path instead of content URI, but it makes no difference
- setting type to "*/*", it then presents a choice on which app to open the dir with, but the result is ultimately the same - "Recent"
- using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent instead, to see if it also has the same problem, and yes, it also points to "Recent"

Note: FileProvider is set up just fine, the uri passed to the intent's data is correct.
Also note: I want to avoid saving those files to "Downloads", if possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Upon completion, tapping on it should open the directory in which the file was saved (my app's external storage directory).

That has never been a feature of Android.

> The intent is set up in the following way and is later passed to a PendingIntent.

`FileProvider` does not support directories. `ACTION_VIEW` does not support directories by default, though some file managers might. `DocumentsContract` has nothing to do with `FileProvider`.

> passing absolute path instead of content URI, but it makes no difference

That should crash your app with a `FileUriExposedException`.

Comment: 1. To be clear, by "should" I just mean that that is the desired result.
2. DocumentsContract specifies the directory mime type, thus the intent automatically opens the file explorer app, instead of presenting a choice of apps.
3. It doesn't though...

Comment: @Serge: "DocumentsContract specifies the directory mime type, thus it automatically opens the file explorer app" -- only for devices with a "file explorer" app that pays attention to that MIME type. There are tens of thousands of Android device models. How many were you planning on testing? It also does not change the fact that `FileProvider` does not support directories.

Comment: I heard this argument before, but so far it doesn't seem to have been a problem, plus all sources were quite old, is it still a problem nowadays?

Comment: @Serge: I would not assume `ACTION_VIEW` to be reliable for any MIME type on any device. Even for something as simple as "open a browser", you have issues (e.g., user does not have access to a Web browser due to running in a restricted profile or due to device owner policies). I would never assume that `ACTION_VIEW` for an unofficial MIME type would work, and `vnd.android.document/directory` is [unofficial](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). Device manufacturers can do what they want.

Comment: What do you mean with FileProvider not supporting directories? It is only used to get the (content) uri of the directory, which, as I noted in the post, is provided just fine. Does uri not support directories?

Comment: @Serge: "What do you mean with FileProvider not supporting directories?" -- I mean that there is no way to get a list of contents of a directory from `FileProvider`. `FileProvider` serves files based on paths, nothing more. It is similar to how a Web server can be configured to serve files but not generate and serve up directory listings. And, even if `FileProvider` (or the Web server) did serve up something for a directory, there is no standard for the format.